# SQL query and subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a question for all the SQL experts.

There is table looking like:

```
 clanname  country     points
 name1     country1    100
 name2     country1    90
 name3     country1    10
 name4     country2    100
 name5     country2    80
 name6     country2    70
```

I would like to make a country ranking involving only the top2 results of each country. so, in this example, the ranking should be:

```
 country    average-points
 country2   95
 country1   90
```

If there a way to get this result with only one SQL query using subqueries?

In reality, I have more than 200 countries.. and thousands of results for each country. But I'd like to filter only the top 30 results of each country.

Right now I managed to get the average of one country using this query:

```
  SELECT 
      location, AVG(warswon)
  FROM
      (SELECT 
           `name`, `location`, `warswon` 
       FROM 
           `clans`
       WHERE 
           location = 'China'
       ORDER BY 
           `clans`.`warswon` DESC 
       LIMIT 30) AS top30ofcountry
```

but how do I get the average results of each country in one query?

Is this possible?

Comment: GROUP BY [fieldname]

Comment: add at the end `GROUP BY location`

Comment: Why do you need a subquery for this?

Comment: This used to be tagged for Sql Server... does that still apply? Sql Server (and most any other database) makes this _easy_, because of support for Windowing functions. This will be **MUCH** harder in MySql than other databases, because it is now the only major database without support for Windowing functions, even though they've been part of the standard for more than 10 years.

Comment: I'm a fan of the ROW_NUMBER function in SQL Server to get the top n per category type of filters. You could add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY points DESC) AS RN` in a sub query or CTE. Then, group by the country `WHERE RN <= ` your cutoff.

Comment: @ConradFrix I was composing my comment when Ed Gibbs changed the tag from SQL Server to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is n per group problem. This is trivial in many DB's using row_number. In MySQL you can do it with user variables

```
SELECT 
  country ,
  avg(points)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
        @num := if(@group = `country`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
        @group := `country` as dummy,
        clanName,
        country,
        points
    FROM
      clans
      JOIN (SELECT @group := NULL, @num := 0) as z
     order by
        country, points desc) as x 
WHERE x.row_number <=2 
GROUP BY 
    country
```

Comment: ok conrad.. i have the feeling this is close to the query i need. i use mysql and all the GROUP BY proposals from former post do not help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Conrad.
I managed to get the reqested result by only changing slightly the code proposed by you.
Here is the final working query for those who have similar questions:

```
SELECT 
location,
avg(warswon)
FROM
(
SELECT 
@num := if(@group = `location`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
@group := `location` as dummy,
name,
location,
warswon
FROM
clans
JOIN (SELECT @group := NULL, @num := 0) as z
order by
location, warswon desc
) as x 
WHERE x.row_number <= 30
GROUP BY `location`
ORDER BY avg(warswon) DESC
```